# Sqlite pagination with PDO

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, pagination

I have managed to paginate by sqlite database using PDO, but being new to databases I am wondering if there is a better or efficient way of doing this? Here  is the code:

```
<?php
try
{
$db = new PDO('sqlite:comments.s3db');
$per_page = '3';
$result = $db->query("SELECT id FROM com ");
$rows = $result ->fetchAll();
$total_records = count($rows);
$pages = ceil($total_records / $per_page); 
$page  = (isset ($_GET['page']))  ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1 ;
$start = ($page - 1) *  $per_page; 
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM com LIMIT $start , $per_page");
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo '<br>' . $row['id'] . '<br>' . $row['name'] . '<br>' . $row['email'] . '<br>';
} ?>
<br><br>
<?php
if ($pages >=  1 && $page <= $pages){
//if ($page>1 && $page <= $pages){$previous=($page -1); echo '<a href="?page=' .$previous. '">Previous</a>';}
for($x=1; $x<=$pages; $x++){ echo ($x == $page) ? ' <strong><a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a></strong> ' : ' <a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a> ';}
//if ($page>1  && $page <= $pages){ $next=($page+1) ; echo '<a href="?page=' .$next. '">Next</a>';}
}
####################### Close Database #######################
$db = NULL;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
print 'Exception : '.$e->getMessage();
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first don't select all records with 'id' in first query. Make it easily with selecting COUNT(id). In result u'll get total rows count:

```
SELECT COUNT(id FROM) com
```

Second notice - format your code. Make it more readable.